# RXJS Pipe - Can you append result of one observable to another and get both results?

Tags: rxjs

So because of the various setups we have I have a habit of running into places where I'd like to add the result of one observable to another, and then using both. Where I need the first one to complete before the other one

```
getUser()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(user => forkJoin([
      of(user),
      getSomethingWithUser(user)
    ]))
  )
  .subscribe((result: [User, SomethingWithUser]) => /*And then use them*/)
```

The various *Map functions just seem to return the result of the final observable, which doesn't work so well when I want the result of them all

Comment: What specifically is wrong with your current solution? I'm confident that it should work.

Comment: @churill I'm not sure if it's wrong. But it does feel kinda off to return an observable with the value of another observable

Comment: I'd say it's correct, but a bit clumsy. BizzyBob's answer looks good :)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do a `map` after the second call and add a nested pipe to access both the first value and second value:

```js
getUser().pipe(
    mergeMap(user => getSomethingWithUser(user).pipe(
        map(something => [user, something])
    )
    .subscribe(([user, something]) => /*And then use them*/)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63462962/1858357) has some more details on using the nested pipe.