# Stringing switchMap(s) together

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am building an editor that lets a user pick 1 account from a set of accounts (aka a Chart of Accounts (COA) )

The author can define the type/subtype that needs to be selected and the editor should offer only choices that meet this preference.

There are 4 steps:

1. Take the Type list and the SubType list, compare those to the set of real life T/STs and return matches  (not every type and every subtype make a valid combination - sync)
2. Fetch the complete COA  from the database (async)
3. Slice the COA based on the allowed T/ST combinations (sync)
4. Populate the config object with the resulting data and return it as an observable

I feel/believe what I have here is a reactive solution.

I have seen/read many articles on using switchmap for this type situation.

This video has been very helpful to me.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Byttv3YpjQk&t=1148s

I think switchmap is indicated over combineLatest as the steps are dependent on the data from previous steps.

The challenge I am facing is that I have coded these as separate statements.

If I try to use the data from the first call (named `a_tst`) in the final observable, I can not.

This is not a blocking issue for me as I do not **NEED** to reach that far back in this particular case. Next time there may be a need...

I am also capturing the data at each step in the config data structure which seems to be a common practice... so maybe that is the answer?

**MY QUESTION - Is there a way to string the switchMaps together such that the trailing switchMaps can reach all the way back through the chain and access the emitted values from the earlier calls?**

Still learning rxjs. Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated...

```js
public hydrate_COA_Editor_Config(config_: COA_Editor_Config, title_: string) : Observable<COA_Editor_Config> {
  const debug: boolean = false;
      
  if (debug) console.log('svc 0.1', title_, config_);

  // get the allowed Type/Subtype combinatinos from the config data structure passed in by caller
  const allowedTST$ = this.get_coa_Allowed_TST_List(config_.AccountTypes, config_.AccountSubTypes);
             
         
  const Accounts$ = allowedTST$.pipe(
    tap(a_tst => {
      if(debug) console.log('1.0', title_, 'allowed tst', a_tst);

      config_.allowed_TST = a_tst;
    }),
    // ask the service for ALL accounts available for this project
    switchMap(a_tst => this.getCOAByProjectId(config_.projectId))
  );   
    
  const allowedAccounts$ = Accounts$.pipe(
    tap(acctHeader => {
      if(debug) console.log('svc 2.0', title_, 'all accts', acctHeader.Accounts);

        // myAccounts = acctHeader.Accounts;
    }),
    // find the set of Accounts which match the caller's indicated types/subtypes
    switchMap(acctHeader => this.get_coa_Allowed_Account_List(acctHeader.Accounts, config_.allowed_TST.items))
  );
    
  // return the config as an observable. It has now been populated w/ all the data needed to do its job.
  const config$: Observable<COA_Editor_Config> = allowedAccounts$.pipe(
    tap(a_accts => {
      // if(debug) console.log('3.0', title_, a_accts);

      config_.allowedAccounts = a_accts;
      config_.hydrated = true;
      // at this point, we have turned the users wishes (allowed types, subtypes) into a list of accounts that match those wishes
    }),
    switchMap(accts => of(config_))
  );
            
  return config$;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass results between chained observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386585/how-to-pass-results-between-chained-observables)

Comment: @bizzybob,  it looks like it might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obs1$.pipe(
  switchMap(result1 => obs2$),
  switchMap(result2 => obs3$), // result1 not available
  switchMap(result3 => obs4$), // result1 and result2 not available
)
```

If you nest the switchMap on the next observable's pipe

```
obs1$.pipe(
  switchMap(result1 => obs2$.pipe(
    switchMap(result2 => obs3$.pipe( // result1 still available
      switchMap(result3 => obs4$)  // result1 and result2 still available
    )
  )
)
```